# Highcharts Barchart Category Word breaks

Tags: highcharts

I have a horizontal Bar and I have text labels on the vertical axys. In German we have some very long words so on a cellphone it sometimes shows like 4/5 labels and bit of charts.

In HTML we use hyphanation with inserting soft hyphons '\u00AD' into the text. Highcharts however only breaks lines with blanks and '-'. Are there any invisible characters that also trigger a linebreak?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exu77/py0kxvtm/7/)

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Something-Bomething-Comething', 'Something Bomething Comething', 'Kom­mu­ni­ka­tions­diens­te'],  
    labels: {
        useHTML: true
    }
},
```

I did try to use the formatter and useHTML but it still doesn't understand the html white-space behaviour, setting a width doesn't work either as it can't break up the long word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper style for `word-break` and `text-overflow`:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Something-Bomething-Comething', 'Something Bomething Comething', 'Kommunikationsdienste'],
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            'word-break': 'break-all', //break-word
            'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
            width: '50px'
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rsvjaxb8/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.style